# Why does "any" type disable typechecking prematurely?

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

Why does using the `any` type disable strict null checks in the below code? Is this a bug?

```js
type SomeType = any;

interface Optional {
  some?: { 
    key: SomeType;
  };
}

interface NotOptional {
  key: SomeType;
}

const opt: Optional = {};

const val: NotOptional = {
  key: opt.some?.key // no error if SomeType is any
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFAhgOxAbgChCBLHYCAJwDMsBjaAeTGBLhywBsoBvQqKAGdEEAPwAuXlH4CoAawghJ8JKkhEBAXyKbiZCjXrQAcnGDNW7LrxkKlsEWog7iddoOBQ4LSRbYduTB5tV3dPADcuSVNzFn9rINtFSW9gADphJFE0uygAejyoHDgoKko4SigSagdVNCrBbDxCTS)

Comment: `any` is an escape hatch from the type checking system. So, it works as expected - it prevents TS from properly evaluating types.

Comment: Apparently I have to inflate my mental image of how bad `any` is. If `opt.some` had already been `any`, then I'd have expected this problem. But on this level? jeez...

Comment: It's pretty bad, yes. I'd recommend avoiding it as much as possible. Not *entirely* as some cases you may need to handle an `any` value for a short amount of time (e.g., common if you want to make a type guard) but that's limited. `any` should not really crop up in most other cases. When you *do* need a value to represent something that you don't know, then use `unknown`. It acts as `any` as it accepts anything assigned to it, however, when used it always requires validation. It's therefore safer. Doesn't bypass the type system.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `unknown`. Unfortunately this `any` comes from code outside of my control. I had to copy that interface and make it use generics to avoid this problem. Really clumsy...

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected since that's how [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is meant to work.